# varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

So I'm writing a quick console program to collect rows of data from an old MySql database my company has and push the rows to a new Sql database. The first 300 or so rows have been fine but all of a sudden I am getting a

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I've tried a number of ways to convert my datetimes now even though there seems to be nothing wrong with the conversion when I put it in a select.

IE:

```
DECLARE @INPUT varchar(30) = '09/25/2010 04:55:47'; 
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @INPUT, 101);`
```

outputs `2010-09-25 04:55:47.000`.

The conversion error is only showing up in the full Sql insert:

```
DECLARE @INPUT varchar(30) = '09/25/2010 04:55:47'; 
INSERT INTO TABLE(A_BUNCH_OF_OTHER_COLUMNS, DATETIME_COLUMN, MORE_COLUMNS) 
          VALUES (A_BUNCH_OF_OTHER_VALUES, CONVERT(datetime, @INPUT, 101), MORE_VALUES);`
```

I see no reason that this isn't working and after asking some of my coworkers, they see nothing wrong with the Sql either.

EDIT: Fixed the INSERT to reflect the actual statement.

Comment: If this is SQL Server please add the tag.  What is `@DT` ? Are any  `A_BUNCH_OF_OTHER_COLUMNS` | `A_BUNCH_OF_OTHER_VALUES` DateTimes? if so the conversion issue is likely there.

Comment: That's because you've got invalid dates in there.  Transfer all the dates over as varchars, then `select * from MuhDateTest where isdate(muhdate) = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(A_BUNCH_OF_OTHER_COLUMNS, CONVERT(datetime, @INPUT, 101), MORE_COLUMNS)
```

In this part you should specify the column of the table which you want to insert values to. You specified the CONVERT method which is not a column.

Answer (score 0):

> If this is SQL Server please add the tag. What is @DT ? Are any A_BUNCH_OF_OTHER_COLUMNS | A_BUNCH_OF_OTHER_VALUES DateTimes? if so the conversion issue is likely there. – Alex K.

Thats where my problem was, there are 3 other datetime fields that are operating times that run over 24 hrs